# How to add slug in URL after domain name with htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a URL like this
https://www.example.com

inner page: https://www.example.com/contact-us

inner page: https://www.example.com/about-us

and i want whenever user visit my site it changes URL to this
https://www.example.com/abc

and then all pages will have this extra slug

inner page:https://www.example.com/abc/contact-us

inner page:https://www.example.com/abc/about-us

Comment: You could use rewrite engine to accomplish this dynamicly or explicitly for each page

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the rewrite module of the apache http server:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/abc/
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /abc/$1 [END]
```

That rule will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" style file) in the hosts `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder. The rewriting module needs to be loaded, obviously. You should definitely prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration, but if you really have to use a dynamic configuration file then take case that it's interpretation is enabled.